# Can't start new VM instance

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to start a new VM on Cloud Compute but it doesn't let me, neither from command line or from the Google Developers Console (the "Create" button is not active, it displays a 'stop' sign when I hover over it). It used to work before. Any ideas what could be going on?

The gcutil command is this (GDC gives me this, but doesn't work either)

> gcutil --service_version="v1" --project="universal-stone-585" addinstance "instance-1" --zone="asia-east1-a" --machine_type="n1-standard-1" --network="default" --external_ip_address="ephemeral" --service_account_scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only" --persistent_boot_disk="true" --auto_delete_boot_disk="true"

Comment: Can you add the screenshot from the console with the error or the error message you get when you execute the command.

Comment: Around that time GCE experienced a network issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-operations/ygmTJKlKCSg are you still experiencing the problem? If so what is the gcutil error message?